# on iOS, will reinstalling Skype delete my chat history?

Tags: iphone, ios, skype

I'm having an issue with Skype on my iPhone, that appears to have been solved for many people by deleting and reinstalling the app.  But I'm hesitant to do this for fear I will lose all my conversation history.

Does anyone know for certain if the chat history on my device will be deleted if I delete the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not delete your chat history.

I reinstalled Skype on a *different* iPhone and the chat history was restored.

Comment: Are you certain ALL of it was restored?  MSFT themselves claim only 30 days is stored in the cloud.  I've got history going back many years.

Comment: You should check Skype from https://web.skype.com/ Any chat you see on the page will restore on your phone

Comment: I just did a scroll...I have chat history going back to 2014.  This iPhone was replaced because I broke the screen and I bought a "renewed" one instead of fixing.  So...it's definitely a phone that never had Skype until I installed it.

Comment: @Lulucmy holy crap, I had no idea there even was a web skype.  That is amazing and super useful... thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and reinstalling Skype will not delete your chat history, but it will reset your recently used emojis and your notifications.